# Reputation on dba.stackexchange.com/users differs from those on individual user pages

Tags: support, reputation, users-page

Currently https://dba.stackexchange.com/users shows 3391 for gbn while https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/630/gbn shows 3492 and similar for other users.

I believe I noticed a decrease of reputations on dba.stackexchange.com/users about 2 days ago.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the default user page view (for your site, this depends on activity) is **year** and the user page has **all time**.

Click the sub-tab to switch to **all time** on /users and it matches.